# Typescripting a ForwardedRef in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using a customized, forwarded checkbox so I can pass that as a component to a `DataGrid`.

```
const CustomCheckbox = ({
  checkboxRef,
  ...props
}: {
  checkboxRef: React.ForwardedRef<unknown>;
}) => (
  <Checkbox
    {...props}
    ref={checkboxRef as React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>}
    sx={{
      color: "#363636",
      "&.Mui-checked": {
        color: "#363636"
      }
    }}
  />
);

const ForwardCustomCheckbox = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <CustomCheckbox {...props} checkboxRef={ref} />;
});


<DataGrid
  ...
  components={{
    BaseCheckbox: ForwardDarkCheckbox
  }}
/>
```

I don't like the use of `as React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>` since I understand this as a kind of bypassing TypeScript.
I couldn't make it work without that.

Do you have any suggestions or is it considered 'okay' using `as` in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `checkboxRef` type to `React.ForwardRef<HTMLButtonElement>`, as it seems this is the only element you wish to allow for this property
2. Use `forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement>` to explicitly define the type of reference this component accepts

```
const CustomCheckbox = ({
  checkboxRef,
  ...props
}: {
  checkboxRef: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
}) => (
  <Checkbox
    {...props}
    ref={checkboxRef}
    sx={{
      color: '#363636',
      '&.Mui-checked': {
        color: '#363636',
      },
    }}
  />
);

const ForwardCustomCheckbox = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement>((props, ref) => {
  return <CustomCheckbox {...props} checkboxRef={ref} />;
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for!